# Double change bar issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have a document where I create a change bar using `<for:change-bar-begin>` and `<for:change-bar-end>`.

It creates a normal change bar in usual cases, but if there is a table inside a list, and that list is inside another list, it creates a double change bar instead of a regular one. List-->List-->Table, for this table double change bar appears.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Specify which XSL FO engine you are using

Comment: This sounds like a bug, so it would help to know which formatter and which version you are using, as @kevin-brown said.

Comment: Using dita-ot-3.5.2

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a fragment of the FO file showing the problem, so that people have an example to test and work with in order to provide an answer.